# Cannot read property 'selection' of undefined

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I'm using ui-grid. But I cannot get the $scope.gridApi from download function. And get the error: Cannot read property 'selection' of undefined. Somebody can tell me the reason? thanks.

```
    $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
        $log.info('gridApi...');
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        $log.info($scope.gridApi);
    };
    $scope.download = function ($event) {
        $event.stopPropagation();
        var selectedRows = $scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
        $log.log('selectedRows....');
        $log.log(selectedRows);
    };
```

Comment: Did you include the ui.grid.selection module as a dependency?

Comment: yes. I did. The manipulation in $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi cannot change the variable value. Why? It refer to ui-grid?

Comment: try to add this to your onRegisterApi: gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function (row) {
                //
            });

Comment: You might forgot to add `ui-grid-selection` to add to your div `<div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" style="height: 100% !important" ui-grid-edit ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-selection></div>`

Answer (score 9):

There are three potential causes:

- firstly, not including selection properly, either not including the module in your js code as a dependency, or not including the directive on your grid definition in your html.  This will result in having a gridApi, but no gridApi.selection
- secondly, trying to call this before onRegisterApi has fired, or defining onRegisterApi on your gridOptions after onRegisterApi has already fired.  This will result in the method not being called, and therefore $scope.gridApi being undefined, which from your error text sounds like what the problem is.
- lastly, problems with your invocation that means the $scope of your download call is different than the $scope you put the gridApi on.  This shouldn't really happen, but I guess it could.  You could tell this by putting a breakpoint in the method to see what $scope it has.

Answer (score 6):

I resolved this issue after checking:

- ui-grid css loaded (`ui-grid.min.css`)
- ui-grid javascript library loaded (`ui-grid.min.js`)
- `'ui.grid'` and `'ui.grid.selection'` added to module initialization  `app = angular.module('app',[`**`'ui.grid','ui.grid.selection'`**])` )
- adding the ui-grid-selection directive to the ui-grid markup
  `<div id="my-grid" ui-grid="gridOptions"` **`ui-grid-selection`** `></div>`

Comment: I was not including ui.grid.selection in app.js or adding the ui-grid-selection directive. Adding these items fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

the answers above are very hepful.
But in my case I resolve it after removing :
         - `ui-grid.core.min.js`
         - `ui-grid.cellnav.min.js`
         - `ui-grid.selection.min.js`

from my loading js and keeping only `ui-grid.min.js`.